# NSMutableArray not retain values

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I Create a class named DataClass there i have this method

```
+(NSMutableArray*) returnList :(NSString *) sql
{

    NSMutableArray *tmpList=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];

    sqlite3 *db;

    NSString *dbPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DB_MyReef" ofType:@"sqlite"];


    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String],&db) ==SQLITE_OK)
    {

        sqlite3_stmt *ss;

        int rv = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1,&ss,NULL);

        if (rv==SQLITE_OK)
        {

            while (sqlite3_step(ss)==SQLITE_ROW) 
            {

                NSString *txt =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ss,0)]; 
                [tmpList addObject:txt];
                [txt release];

            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(ss);
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);


    return tmpList; 


}
```

In my other class named UserSelect i create.

in h file

```
@interface UserSelect : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource> {

    NSMutableArray *List;
    UIPickerView *myPicker; 

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *List;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIPickerView *myPicker;


@end
```

and m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {



    [super viewDidLoad];

    //List=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init;

    NSString *sql;
        //Loading Data
        if ([self.title isEqualToString:@"Marca Teste"]) 
        {
            sql=@"SELECT TESTMARK FROM TBL_TESTSMARK ORDER BY TESTMARK";
        }
        else
        {
            sql=@"SELECT PT_PARAMNAME FROM TBL_PARAMETERS "
            "WHERE COD IN "
            "(SELECT A.CODTEST FROM TBL_TEST AS A  "
            "INNER JOIN  "
            "TBL_TESTSMARK AS B "
            "ON  "
            "A.CODTESTMARK =B.COD "
            "WHERE " 
            "B.TESTMARK='Salifert')";
        }

    self.List=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.List=[[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[DataClass returnList:sql]]retain];

    myPicker=[[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    myPicker.delegate=self;
    myPicker.dataSource=self;

        /*for (NSString *ts in List) {
            NSLog(@"%@",ts);
        }*/

        [self.view addSubview:myPicker];    


    }
```

Ok, i call this method and this return is a expected.

But in the UiPickerView methods my List variable only retain the first object in the NSMutable array.

These are the UIPicker methods

```
#pragma mark pickerView

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    NSLog(@"%@",@"numberOfComponentsInPickerView");
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@"%@",@"numberOfRowsInComponent");

    return [List count];
}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *) pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger) row forComponent:(NSInteger) component
{
    NSString *txt=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[self.List objectAtIndex:(int)row]];
    return txt;
    [txt release];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *txt=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[self.List objectAtIndex:(int)row]];

    [DataClass writePlist:txt toKey:TEST_MARK]; 

    [txt release];


}
```

I tried to boot List in many ways, what`s wrong?

Comment: You got a good answer from rudy, I would just like to add this line is unnecessary: `self.List=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` because you set that property to something else on the next line.

Comment: More than unnecessary; it leaks the created array. /cc @fichek

Comment: This code was after many changes, so why he was not working at all.
But still do not understand how it worked in return.
 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

```
NSString *txt =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(ss,0)]; 
[tmpList addObject:txt];
[txt release];
```

The string txt is autoreleased (`NSString stringXXX` functions return an autoreleased string). Then you add it to the `tmpList` and explicitly release it. As soon as the autorelease pool is drained, the string will be released. In other words, you over-release the string. Remove

```
[txt release];
```

and the values should be retained by `tmpList`. Since tmpList is autoreleased too, it is not sure if this matters. It could give you a runtime error.

This is also suspicious:

```
self.List=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.List=[[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[DataClass returnList:sql]]retain];
```

The first alloc-init is totally unnecessary. If the property was synthesized properly, it will not produce a leak, but it doesn't make any sense. Remove the first of these two lines.

Also, your `returnList:` method returns a string, but you use it as array in the second line I quoted above.

All in all, there are quite a few logical errors in your code. You might want to run it through the debugger and the analyzer (menu Product - Analyze).

Comment: I've tried is also not working!
in viewDidLoad the List array is correct with all value, in the comment for the result is shown, a problem is in UIPickerView methods

Comment: Rudy thanks very much! in the target!
one more doubt why in the viewDidLoad the array is correct?